# Trying to count certain characters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want the code to count `"`, `!`, `?`, `,` but when I run the code it counts all characters typed. Could anyone tell me where I messed up?

```
def how_eligible():
    total = 0
    x = ('"','!','?',',')
    y = raw_input('Write your essay here.')
    for y in x:
        if y in x:
            total = total + 1
    print total
```

Comment: You write `for y in x`. But `y` is the input string...

Comment: `sum(y.count(char) for char in x)`

Comment: be aware that you are overwriting the y variable in the for loop thus making the raw_input y useless. another thing is that if you say "for something in iterable", then (something in iterable) is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase want to know.. A Pythonic 1 liner solution

```
x = ('"','!','?',',')
y = input('Write your essay here.')
len([i for i in y if i in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your double for loop as

```
for c in y:
    if c in x:
        total = total + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Counter from the collections module:

```
from collections import Counter

in_s = 'abc?c?"!'
need = ['"', '!', '?']

char_count = Counter(in_s)

for c in need:
    print(c, char_count[c])
```